# Insert row for each $_POST with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, post, pdo, foreach

I have a dynamic form generated by a while loop that looks like this:

```
<form>
<?php while ($questions = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $questions['question_id']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

I am trying to insert each 'response' and 'question_id' into its own row. I am not sure whether to send the $_POST variables as arrays like text[] or do a foreach loop or both?

Essentially I want to do the following:

```
foreach($_POST) {
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO responses SET text=:text, question_id=:question_id);
    $query->bindValue(':text', $_POST['text'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':question_id', $_POST['question_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
}
```

I have read it is also inefficient to execute the query multiple times like this.

What is the best approach to this?

Comment: Remember to always filter your $_POST, don't just insert $_POST fields into database.

Comment: @Adherence It's being bound to placeholders here, so things are okay. There's a missing `"` in the `prepare` line though.

Answer (score 2):

Easy, you just need to improve your loop a little bit and you only need one query...

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO responses SET text=:text, question_id=:question_id");

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if($key == "text") {
        $query->bindValue(':text', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    } else if($key == "question_id") {
        $query->bindValue(':question_id', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
}

$query->execute();
```

Comment: how can I do this when both inputs are arrays? name="question_id[]" and name="text[]"

Answer (score 0):

set the id of the textarea array like this

```
<form>
<?php while ($questions = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
<textarea name="text[<?php echo $questions['question_id']; ?>]"></textarea>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

then you can loop over the $_POST['text'] array

```
foreach($_POST['text'] as $k => $val) {
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO responses SET text=:text, question_id=:question_id);
    $query->bindValue(':text', $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':question_id', $k, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Post values are like:

```
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
```

And at the Server side:

```
$_POST["text"]
```

If you want to Transfer multidimensional Array throu POST, use this:

```
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
```

And at the Server side:

```
$_POST["text"][0]; //1
$_POST["text"][1]; //2
$_POST["text"][2]; //3
```

Sure it works with keys:

```
<textarea name="text[foo]"></textarea>
<textarea name="text[boo]"></textarea>
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
```

And at the Server side:

```
$_POST["text"]["foo"]; //1
$_POST["text"]["boo"]; //2
$_POST["text"][0]; //3
```